# Cookies not appearing in Chrome but they appear in Fiddler

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, fiddler

In Chrome I visit a page. Looking at the developer tools I see that for a certain domain there are no cookies at the `Application` tab. In the `Network` tab, if I look at the requests to that same domain, none of them contain cookies. However, if I use Telerik Fiddler, I see for these requests, in the cookies tab: "Request sent 322 bytes of Cookie data", and the corresponding cookies. Any explanation for that? Why don't I see them in Chrome?